# Kotlinx SerialName not as a constant

Tags: android, serialization, kotlinx

I am parsing a json object and there multiple values for same field for the different languages.

For example:

```
"subtitle_en": "Hello World",
"subtitle_de": "Hallo Welt"
```

I want to extract the subtitle depending on the language I have on my device.

I tried doing this:

`@SerialName("subtitle_${Locale.getDefault().language}") val subtitle: String,`

But I am getting an error `An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant`. Does anyone have an idea how to do this with another way?